# Black screen when im trying to make double buffered GDI overlay

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+, gdi, buffering

Im trying to create double buffered gdi overlay over desktop but all what i get is black screen with red line

```
    HDC hdc = GetDC(0);

    HDC mem_handle = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP bitmap_hndl = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 1920, 1080);

    HBITMAP old0 = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(mem_handle, bitmap_hndl);

    HPEN pen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 5, RGB(255, 0, 0));
    HGDIOBJ oldpen = SelectObject(mem_handle, pen);

    POINT Dots[2];
    Dots[0] = { 500, 500 };
    Dots[1] = { 200, 200 };
    DWORD NumDots = 2;
    PolyPolyline(mem_handle, Dots, &NumDots, 1ull);

    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, mem_handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT);

    SelectObject(mem_handle, oldpen);
    SelectObject(mem_handle, old0);

    DeleteObject(pen);
    DeleteObject(bitmap_hndl);
    DeleteDC(mem_handle);
    ReleaseDC(0, hdc);
```

Im tried to use alphabland and transparentblt but nothing changed

Comment: Your source device context `mem_handle` is only drawn with red lines. See [Capturing an Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/capturing-an-image) for more information.

Comment: You cannot reliably render into a device context you do not own (such as the one returned from `GetDC(0)`. If you need a render target, you have to create a window.

Comment: *You must set your window as child of "WorkerW" window.* See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1386630/doubts-about-the-window-of-program-manager for code implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a "gdi overlay over the desktop" by just painting to the screen's device context. Painting to `GetDC(NULL)` will, maybe, get some pixels displayed for a few milliseconds before something else paints over them.

Windows is called "Windows" for a reason. If you want something to persist on the screen you need to paint it in the WM_PAINT handler of a window you create. Otherwise, you can't control when what you paint will be overwritten.